# Mechanics of a $(0,2)$-tensor and a bi-vector acting on 2 vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

Both bivectors and $(0,2)$-tensors are mathematical structures that take in $2$ vectors and produce a scalar. Similar as in [this prior post I wrote](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2436543/152225), I would like to dumb down the mechanics of these operations with a simple example.

The goal is to understand at a very immediate level why

> [$C_{ij} \,dx^i \wedge dx^j = C_{ij}\, \frac 1 2 \left(dx^i \otimes dx^j - dx^j \otimes dx^i \right)\tag 1$](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/tensor-and-wedge-products.150289/)

Let's say that we have two covectors: $\beta =\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt \pi &\sqrt[3]\pi\end{bmatrix}$ and $\gamma=\begin{bmatrix}\frac 1 3&\frac 15\end{bmatrix},$ which will form the coefficients for the wedge and tensor products.

The wedge product is $\beta \wedge \gamma$

$$\begin{align}
\beta \wedge \gamma&=
\sqrt \pi \frac 13 \;e^1\wedge e^1 + \sqrt\pi \frac 15 \;e^1 \wedge e^2 +
\sqrt[3]\pi\frac 13\; e^2 \wedge e^1 + \sqrt[3]\pi \frac 15 e^2\wedge e^2
\\[2ex]
&=
0 + \sqrt\pi \frac 15 \;e^1 \wedge e^2 +
\sqrt[3]\pi\frac 13\; e^2 \wedge e^1 + 0
\\[2ex]
&=\left( \sqrt \pi \frac 15 - \sqrt[3]\pi \frac 13 \right) \; e^1\wedge e^2\tag 2
\end{align}$$

If we feed two vectors to this form, say $\vec v=\begin{bmatrix} 2&3\end{bmatrix}^\top$ and $\vec w=\begin{bmatrix}4&5 \end{bmatrix}^\top$ we end up with

$$\begin{align}
\left(\left( \sqrt \pi \frac 15 - \sqrt[3]\pi \frac 13 \right) \; e^1\wedge e^2\right)[\vec v, \vec w] &=\left( \sqrt \pi \frac 15 - \sqrt[3]\pi \frac 13 \right) \; \det\begin{bmatrix}2&4\\3&5 \end{bmatrix}\\[2ex]
&=\left( \sqrt \pi \frac 15 - \sqrt[3]\pi \frac 13 \right)\left(2\cdot 5-3\cdot 4\right)
\end{align}\tag 3$$

---

Now coparing to the tensor product $\beta\otimes\gamma$:

$$\beta \otimes \gamma =\begin{bmatrix} 
\sqrt \pi \frac 13 \; e^1\otimes e^1 & \sqrt \pi \frac 1 5 \;e^1\otimes e^2\\
\sqrt[3]\pi\frac 1 3 \, e^2\otimes e^1 & \sqrt[3]\pi \frac 1 5\,e^2\otimes e^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Feeding the vectors $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ first as $\left(\beta \otimes \gamma\right)[\vec v, \vec w],$ followed by $\left(\beta \otimes \gamma\right)[\vec w, \vec v]:$

$$\begin{align}
\left(\beta \otimes \gamma\right)[\vec v, \vec w]&=
\begin{bmatrix}2&3\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
\sqrt \pi \frac 13 \; e^1\otimes e^1 & \sqrt \pi \frac 1 5 \;e^1\otimes e^2\\
\sqrt[3]\pi\frac 1 3 \, e^2\otimes e^1 & \sqrt[3]\pi \frac 1 5\,e^2\otimes e^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}4\\5\end{bmatrix}\\[2ex]
&=\sqrt \pi \frac 13 4\cdot 2 + \sqrt \pi \frac 15 5\cdot 2+\sqrt[3]\pi \frac 13 4\cdot 3+\sqrt[3]\pi\frac 15 5 \cdot 3
\end{align}$$

And

$$\begin{align}
\left(\beta \otimes \gamma\right)[\vec w, \vec v]&=
\begin{bmatrix}4&5\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
\sqrt \pi \frac 13 \; e^1\otimes e^1 & \sqrt \pi \frac 1 5 \;e^1\otimes e^2\\
\sqrt[3]\pi\frac 1 3 \, e^2\otimes e^1 & \sqrt[3]\pi \frac 1 5\,e^2\otimes e^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix}\\[2ex]
&=\sqrt \pi \frac 13 2\cdot 4 + \sqrt \pi \frac 15 3\cdot 4+\sqrt[3]\pi \frac 13 2\cdot 5+\sqrt[3]\pi\frac 15 3 \cdot 5
\end{align}$$

The difference is therefore:

$$\left(\beta \otimes \gamma\right)[\vec v, \vec w]-\left(\beta \otimes \gamma\right)[\vec w, \vec v]=\left(\sqrt \pi \frac 15-\sqrt[3]\pi\frac 13\right)\left(2\cdot 5 - 3 \cdot 4 \right)\tag 4$$

> Now, (4) is identical to (3). The question is, then, about the $\frac 12$ factor to fulfill equation (1)? Why is there no need to divide (4) by $2$ to fulfill equation (1)?

Comment: It's pretty standard to use the term *$2$-form* for an alternating covariant tensor of rank $2$ on a given vector space and reserve *bivector* for an alternative contravariant tensor of rank $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unusual---and possibly a source of confusion here---to write tensor products as matrices with tensor entries.

Denote the underlying vector space by $\Bbb V$. For a covariant $2$-tensor $T$ we pick a basis, say, $(E^a)$ of $\Bbb V$, denote the dual frame by $(e^a)$, and form the matrix $[T]$ whose $(a, b)$ entry respectively is the component $T_{ab} = T(E^a, T^b)$, that is, the coefficient $T_{ab}$ in the decomposition $T = \sum_{a, b} T_{ab} e^a \otimes e^b$. If $T$ is antisymmetric, then $T_{ab} = T(E_a, E_b) = -T(E_b, E_a) = T_{ba}$, in which case $[T]$ itself is antisymmetric.

In the case in the question, in which $\Bbb V = \Bbb F^2$ and $T$ is a wedge product $\alpha \wedge \beta$ of $1$ forms, $[\alpha \wedge \beta]$ has a single independent component, namely,
$$[\alpha \wedge \beta]_{12} = (\alpha \wedge \beta)_{12} = (\alpha \wedge \beta)(E_1, E_2) = \alpha(E_1) \beta(E_2) - \beta(E_1) \alpha(E_2) = \alpha_1 \beta_2 - \alpha_2 \beta_1 ,$$ so that
$$[\alpha \wedge \beta] = \pmatrix{0 & \alpha_1 \beta_2 - \alpha_2 \beta_1 \\ -(\alpha_1 \beta_2 - \alpha_2 \beta_1) & 0} .$$

Comment: I totally see that I went down the rabbit's hole with the matrix expression, but I would like, nonetheless, to understand at which point there is a mistake in the OP.

Comment: I would say on in first display equations where the $2 \times 2$ matrices occur, since the notation with tensor entries doesn't have any predefined meaning.

Comment: If you have a change, please take a quick look at the matrix expressions in [this post](https://www.quora.com/In-plain-English-whats-the-difference-between-the-tensor-product-and-the-wedge-product/answer/Nathan-Kaye-5?ch=10&share=1e8b4ab0&srid=utSnl).

Comment: Anything in particular about them? That last display equation looks to be the same as the last display equation in my answer, except that it's generalized to an $n$-dimensional vector space.

Comment: I made some vey substantial changes to the OP, as I'm struggling to understand the mechanics behind these otherwise rather abstract concepts. Just in case you feel inclined to taking a look. I apologize for actually changing quite a bit the premise of the question - the final intention as stated in the OP, remains unaltered.

Comment: In general it's regarded to be poor etiquette to change a question substantially after an answer has been given (though in this case, I think my answer applies just as well). If you can articulate a more specific question (posted in this thread or as a new question in its own right) I'm happy to take a look, but my first recommendation is to stop writing tensors as components of matrices representing a tensor: (In this context) it is nonstandard, and I think it's responsible for much of the confusion here.

Comment: I totally agree regarding the etiquette. As you can see I got rid of the matriceal issue practically completely. I just need to understand the $\frac 12$ issue.

Comment: I suggest formulating that as a new question (in particular posed without all of the extraneous material).

Comment: (If you decide to do, feel free to paste a link in this thread, in which case I'll take a look at it myself.)

Comment: I have eliminated the matrices altogether - again, I'm sorry about the shift in format. Not my MO, but I really want to get this, and I think I was confusing the coefficients of the wedge and tensor products with the actual vectors they act on. Now I just need to see that $\frac 12.$ If you think you can provide an answer at my level and consisent with the OP as it is now, I'll be happy to post the question as it is as a separate entry; roll back the OP to what it was yesterday; and if I understand your answers - no doubt they are correct - accept them both.

Comment: For what it's worth, the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ is a matter of convention, and not a universal one. See $\S 12$ of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* for a good discussion of this.

Comment: Are you implicitly saying that my calculations are correct in the OP as it stands right now?

Comment: I still don't quite follow all of your calculations, but if the only outstanding issue is the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ then your calculation must be correct for some choice of convention.

Comment: Comment to self: page 208 pdf Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

Answer (score 1):

Just as a pictorial illustration of the workings of alternating linear algebra and wedge products - kind of a footnote.

---

**Alternating multilinear functions:**

The following is an example of $\Lambda^3(\mathbb R^6)^\star:$

[image]

a function $dx$ taking in $3$ vectors in $\mathbb R^6,$ i.e. $dx_{134}(v_
{1},v_{2},v_{k=3}),$ and returning a determinant of a matrix of the rows $1,$$3$ and $4$ - the $k\times k$ matrix composed of the corresponding elements $1,$ $3$ and $4$ of the input vectors: $$\mathbb R^6 \times \mathbb R^6 \times \mathbb R^6 \to\mathbb R.$$ All these possible such operations form a vector space with basis

$$\begin{align}\{dx_{123},dx_{124},dx_{125},dx_{126},\\dx_{134},dx_{135},dx_{136},\\dx_{145},dx_{146},\\dx_{156},\\dx_{234},dx_{235},dx_{236},\\dx_{245},dx_{246},\\dx_{256},\\dx_{345},dx_{346},dx_{356},\\dx_{456}\}\end{align} $$ of dimension ${6\choose 3}=20
.$

---

**Wedge product:**

The wedge product of, for example, an element $dx_{134}\in\Lambda^3(\mathbb R^6)^\star$ and an element $dx_{65}\in\Lambda^2(\mathbb R^6)^\star:$

[image]

will be an element $dx_{134}\wedge dx_{65} =dx_{13465}=-dx_{13456}\in\Lambda^5(\mathbb R^6)^\star.$

Or, as a different example, $dx_i \wedge dx_j = dx_{ij} = - dx_j \wedge dx_i = d_{ji}.$

These operators ($dx_i,$ $dx_i\wedge dx_j,$ etc) can have coefficients, and these coefficients can be functions. In fact, both the coefficients of these forms and the vectors fed into them can be functions, as in $z dx\wedge dy.$ If $g(u,v)=\begin{bmatrix}v \cos u & v\sin v & 3u \end{bmatrix}^\top,$ the pullback of $z dx\wedge dy$ on $g$ will be the determinant of the matrix of partial derivatives:

$$Dg =\begin{bmatrix}
-v\sin u & \cos u \\
v \cos u & \sin u \\
3 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$g^\star (z dx\wedge dy) = 3u\left(g^\star dx \wedge g^\star dy \right)=3u\left( -v \sin^2u \,du\wedge dv + v \cos^2u \,dv\wedge du\right)$$

as explained [here](https://youtu.be/lpicAI53e04?t=1893).

Comment: [Here](https://youtu.be/wlo2V8H5khM) is a great presentation on the topic.